# User defined Regular expression pattern match, how to?

Tags: regex, shell, sed, awk

I got a complicated file having the contents as:

[Original File](https://bitbucket.org/albertop/twophaseeulerpimplefoam/src/d009d119637c/testCases/fallingBlockFine/system/fvSolution)

```
AAA
{      
  "(BBB|KKK)"
  {
    B_1 abc;
    B_2 bcd;
    B_3 efg;
    B_4 xyz;
  }

  CCC
  {
    C_1 cbc;
    C_2 dcd;
  }
}

DDD
{

  EEE
  {
    E_1 ebc;
    E_2 fcd;
  }

  "(FFF|LLL|MMM|NNN)"
  {
    F_1 gbc;
    F_2 hcd;
  }
}

GGG
{
  G_1 ibc;
}

HHH
{
  III
  {
    JJJ
    {
      J_1 jbc;
      J_2 kbc;
    }
  }
}
```

I want to using awk or some tools to get the output as (just take an example)

```
F_1 = gbc
G_1 = ibc
J_1 = jbc
```

My question is: how to define a regular expression pattern so to match, first, say search a key word `FFF`, then output the contents that are between the closest bracelets `{` and `}`?

```
F_1 gbc;
F_2 hcd;
```

And then this contents can be further piped and using `grep` I can get the value `gbc` for item `F_1`.

Anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: What would happen with keyword `DDD` ?

Comment: Yes, there are indeed a few first level and third level type information that I need too. Please see my edited post.

Comment: This feels like one of those questions where you may think you can ask for something small and then expand on it later but your later requirements may require a completely different solution to the original and so people reading the thread and posting answers might get frustrated and lose interest so make sure you post your real, final expected output given some truly representative sample input.

Comment: @Daniel You didn't really answer the question though, what _exact_ output do you expect upon given a non-innermost keyword, e.g. `DDD` or `HHH`?

Comment: No, not AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD, EEE, FFF, GGG, HHH, etc. They have no value, they are the dictionary name! Not the key name. The key name are ended with *_[123456789], they are what I want to output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will allow you to "define a regular expression pattern so to match, first, say search a key word FFF, then output the contents that are between the closest bracelets { and }":

```
$ gawk -v RS='\0' '{ print gensub(/.*\yFFF\y[^{]+{[[:space:]]*\n([^}]+)\n[[:space:]]*}.*/,"\\1","") }' file
    F_1 gbc;
    F_2 hcd;
```

Do NOT pipe the output to grep. Whatever you want can be done easily within the single awk call.

Comment: WOW, this is beyond my reach right now. Thanks anyway! I am writing a program with c++ right now, which is much easier for me to handle this situation. Plus, in my file as you can see from the link I provided in this post, there are many repetition of the keyword `U`, instead of a simple keyword `FFF`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script that should be okay for second level nested group data only:

```
$ awk -v var="FFF" '$1=="}"{p=0}p{sub(/^ */,"");print};$1==var{p=1;getline}' file
F_1 gbc;
F_2 hcd;
```

Comment: Thanks, but isn't there any clean solution? :)

Comment: @Daniel The "clean" solution is to use/write a proper parser for OpenFOAM's fvSolution file format.